# LineGraph Using Android plot

Tags: android, graph

I have create simple line chart using Android Plot library.
 what i want to do is:
 set X range Upto Seven results(I have done this).
 and set max value of Y is 100. 
 currently it takes max value of array as max Y value.
 i want like this:
  [image]

any suggetion?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is that you are confusing the number of data points with the maximum value of the axis. Your x-axis is just the number of data points, it has not value as such. The y-axis will contain the same number of points - however I believe you want to set the maximum value of the y-axis to 100 because it is a percentage. You can do this by using [setRangeBoundaries](http://androidplot.com/javadoc/0.4.3/com/androidplot/xy/XYPlot.html#setRangeBoundaries%28java.lang.Number,%20com.androidplot.xy.BoundaryMode,%20java.lang.Number,%20com.androidplot.xy.BoundaryMode%29)

Comment: hey it works fine but can you know how to draw line at middle of graph view ?

Comment: have you tried adding a second plot which is a line plot (and no markers) with the points all set to 50. I currently don't have my android dev environment set up to test it with otherwise I'd try it out and send some code - hope it works!